# How can I bypass the annoying Quora login popup?

Tags: quora

Sometimes a Google search will show a Quora page and when you visit it, you are *forced* to sign up or log in. I do have a Quora account but I don't want to sign in on every computer I work on.

How can the login popup be bypassed so that I don't have to spend several minutes in signing in or signing up when I only need to see that Quora question for something very quick?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is very annoying to see the login popup. They could have used the same model as [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) when registration is only used to make you vote and ask questions.

Anyways, when you encounter the problem you face, append the following in the URL:

```
?share=1
```

and the popup will go away.

[image: no popup]

---

Credits of this tip: [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/186954/bypass-quora-login-and-see-all-answers/)